# How to Set TimeoutException in C# and redirec to CustomErrorPage.aspx

Tags: asp.net, exception, command

I am trying to set the TimeoutException for command and on which if " Command TimeoutException" occurs in code it must go to catch block and further redirect to customerror.aspx page.
Code is:

```
try
{
   command.Timeout=1; //which is in seconds for testing i have set it to one.
   //some code here
   // if TimeoutException occurs, it must go to following block which doesnthappen
   //And  it goes to catch 2: block..! Why is it so...?
}

//catch 1:
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
     Response.Redirect("CustomError.aspx");

}

//catch 2:
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Response.Redirect("CustomError.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `catch 2` block - what's the full type of exception that is thrown?
it might not be a `TimeoutException`, but would be caught by `Exception` since that's the base type for exceptions in .NET.

Comment: Nested exception like the one above when ever one is cached the rest are ignored more like if .. else if

Comment: ya i agree...!But,why doesn't it goes for catch 1 block code and when will the TimeoutException occurs? when i have set it for 1Second it must go to TimeoutException but it fails...why? :-(

Comment: Because the exception you actually get is _not_ a TimeoutException - probably some type of database-specific exception

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to catch a database command timeout exception. That does not throw a `.net` `Timeout exception` but instead a `SqlException` with text "Timeout expired... ".

Since you are not catching the `sqlException`, it is going to the catch2 block in this case.

check out [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/614aff74-a446-4cf0-9980-a50f490ec5d3) link.